# How to find the basis for the set of all infinite sequences such that the addition of two terms in a row yields the subsequent term?

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, vector-spaces, fibonacci-numbers

Like the question asks, if I have a subspace, F, of $ \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ (the set of all infinite sequences that follow $(a_1, a_2,...)$) such that the infinite sequence must satisfy $$a_i + a_{i+1} = a_{i+2} \text{ for all } i \geq 2$$ ow could I find a basis for F?

My initial thought process stemmed from the idea that the basis must be a linearly independent set of sequences such that multiples of one sequence cannot produces multiples of the other sequences in the basis, but there's no specified starting point of the sequence satisfying F, and there's no specification that the sequence must consist of real numbers.

My assumption is that the basis would be something like $\{(a_1 , a_2,...): a_1 \in \mathbb{R} \text{ and } a_2 \in \mathbb{R}\}$ where $a_1 \text{ and } a_2$ must be linearly independent, but I don't necessarily know how to describe that in mathematical terms for the basis.

Comment: If you take the solution with initial values $a_1=1,\ a_2=0$ and the solution with initial values $b_1=0,\  b_2=1$, those two solutions will be linearly independent, and any solution can be expressed as a linear combination of those two. For instance, if $c_n$ is the solution with initial values $c_1=17$ and $c_2=12$ then $c_n=17a_n+12b_n$.

Comment: @bof Ohhhhh, i get it. So can I describe the basis in R^2?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The basis I suggested consists of the two sequences $1,0,1,1,2,3,5,8,\dots$ and $0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,\dots$. The solution space is $2$-dimensional because you have a **second order** homogeneous linear  recurrence ($a_n$ depends only on $a_{n-1}$ and $a_{n-2}$), so a solution is uniquely determined by $2$ consecutive values.. say $a_1$ and $a_2$.

Comment: You say it's a subspace of ${\bf R}^{\bf N}$, but then you say there's no specification that the sequence must consist of real numbers. Huh?

Comment: @GerryMyerson ugh, I meant integers, sorry.

Comment: @bof gosh, i'm an idiot, yes you are correct